# URL rewriting not doing what it's supposed to do, but code seems fine

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been working on a website for a friend lately, on which she can upload images of her paintings. Along with those images some information like size and techniques are entered. These images are added to an album which are then displayed in the gallery. The functionality is there, now I just want to rewrite the urls so they don't look like `album.php?album_id=xx&name=xx`. I want the urls to be like `album/id/name`. To do that, I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) album.php?album_id=$1&naam=$2 [NC]
```

This means that if I'd go to `album/1/test`, it should get the data for that album and display it, but it doesn't fully work. It does get the data for that album, but the image isn't loaded (even though when inspecting the source it's loaded in correctly) and there isn't any styling anywhere on the page, even though the stylesheets are loaded in correctly. The strange thing is, that if I go to `album.php?album_id=1&naam=test` the whole page works, so I know the code in the album.php page works. I have also created a `test.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php
echo 'ID: ' . $_GET['album_id'] . '<br>';
echo 'Naam: ' . $_GET['naam'];
```

With the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) test.php?album_id=$1&naam=$2 [NC]
```

If I go to `test/1/test`, I get what I want:

```
ID: 1
Naam: test
```

So I know the rewriting works.

The code for album.php can be found [here](http://pastie.org/10226536)

Any idea what is causing the styling to not load and the image to not load correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using relative paths for your stylesheet and your images.

If you use for example `images/album.jpg` for your image, it will look for:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/images/album.jpg
```

when you load `index.php` directly.

However, it will look for:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/album/1/test/images/album.jpg
```

with your rewrite rule in place.

An easy solution is to always use absolute paths, relative to the root of the web-server, like:

```
/images/image.jpg
/styles/styles.css
```

Note the slash `/` at the start.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a problem with the paths. I already had a `$root` variable which I use for the menu, so I just use that to direct to the correct path for the images and css. Problem solved.